# Pause issue in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a clock but I'm running into trouble.

```
:jual
set /p prompt=jual-
if %prompt% == varset goto varset
if %prompt% == varview goto varview
if %prompt% == clock goto clock
if %prompt% == games goto games
if %prompt% == exit exit
:clock
cls
echo %time%
echo Press any key to exit.
timeout 0 >nul
goto clock
pause >nul
goto jual
```

For the clock, I want it to redirect with user input back to :jual but have it repeat so it actually displays the current time. How do I fix this?

Comment: cls,print time and single letter menu - but use choice.exe with timeout

Answer (score 1):

something like that?

```
:loop
cls
choice /t 1 /c svcgxz /m "[varSet, varView, Clock, Games, eXit] %time% jual- " /d z
if errorlevel 6 goto :loop
if errorlevel 5 goto :eof
if errorlevel 4 goto games
if errorlevel 3 goto clock
if errorlevel 2 goto varview
if errorlevel 1 goto varset
```

Comment: A bit more sophisticated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off
:loop
cls
Echo Menu of today %date% - %time:~0,8% is
Echo:
Echo [S]  varSet
Echo [V]  varView
Echo [C]  Clock
Echo [G]  Games
Echo [X]  eXit
Echo:

choice /t 1 /c svcgxz /m "jual- " /d z
if errorlevel 6 goto :loop
if errorlevel 5 goto :eof
if errorlevel 4 call :games
if errorlevel 3 call :clock
if errorlevel 2 call :varview
if errorlevel 1 call :varset
goto :loop

:games
:clock
:varview
:varset
Echo You selected %0
timeout /t 2 >NUL
goto :eof
```