# Batch: How to prompt for input and continue if timed out?

Tags: batch-file, timeout

I know the `timeout /t 60` way to get a delay with automatic continue and the `set /p var="prompt"` for getting user input but is there any change to do both; ask and have a timeout to continue if nothing is entered? I would use it for a sort of get set screen for my looping script to change script settings.

Comment: How much input do you need? 1 key/char or more?

Comment: 1 key will do nicely.

Comment: The one keystroke choice command also has a timeout option, see `choice /?`or visit http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html . You may choose a default answer when timing out. See this [menu example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44774287/6811411)

Comment: You overtook me while writing. :)

Comment: Is there something for user input where amount of entered text isn't known? I'm also thinking of opening a new window and letting the parent window/script countdown and terminate the child window/process if no input was given within xx time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at `choice /?` to request a key and abort with a timeout.

For example:

```
CHOICE /T 10 /C YN /D Y
```

will wait 10 seconds for Y (Yes) or N (No), otherwise the default (/D) will be taken, which is Y (Yes) in this example.

To check the result (either keypressed or default value), you have to check `%ERRORLEVEL%`.

```
@echo off
cls
CHOICE /T 5 /C YN /D Y
set _e=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %_e%==1 echo Y&goto :done
if %_e%==2 echo N&goto :done

echo Error
echo %_e%

:done
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't remember `choice`, I've used it before like this years ago. I just wish it had the countdown as in timeout, other than that this is perfect, thanks! I've got a script running nicely now.

Comment: You mean that the user can see, how many seconds are left until timeout?

Comment: Yes but now that I think about it it's better this way since it's easier to scroll back to see what the script has been doing.

Comment: @Bricktop One option is to use `timeout` with the desired time, followed by `choice` with a short /T. Tradeoffs are extra input to skip `timeout` to see `choice` and less time to respond to `choice`. In my case `choice` is too limiting with a max timeout of 9999, so I'm padding it with `timeout` anyway.