# Exiting batch script on input

Tags: batch-file, stdin, io-redirection

I have a batch file doing repetitive work, that is executed from a C# application (a jobs manager) as a Process, and needs to be stopped in a "gentle" way (not `Process.Kill()`, but rather an input read between work iterations).

I chose redirecting the script's stdin and sending a "stop" line when it's time. In the batch I have to read the "stop" command (or even any input, just get a line) and exit. However it turns out to be easier said than done.

The following command gets any input and exits:

```
set /p x=&exit
```

But, being single threaded, the batch can't do iterations while waiting for input. So I see 2 ways of dealing with it:

**1. Multi-threading**

I haven't found any way to do it in batch except the `start` command. I tried this:

```
start set /p x=&exit
```

But it appears to create a **new process**, so my input doesn't reach it, and even if I found a way to redirect it there, calling exit in it wouldn't help me in any way since it's not the process of my batch. Here's an entire script example:

```
@echo off
start set /p x=&exit
:work
ping 127.0.0.1
goto :work
```

**2. Timeout on input reading**

There's the `choice` command as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999665/batch-how-to-prompt-for-input-and-continue-if-timed-out). But the timeout doesn't work when the batch is executed from C# - the command keeps waiting for input even though a timeout and a default are defined. Here's an entire script example:

```
@echo off
:work
ping 127.0.0.1
choice /T 5 /C sc /D c
set _e=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %_e%==1 echo Stopped
if %_e%==2 echo Continue&goto :work
```

The "s" from "stop" is enough to successfully stop the script, but only 1 iteration happens - the choice command just keeps waiting for input. Here's the C# code spawning the process, pretty standard:

```
            Process script = new Process();
            script.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("batfile.bat");
            script.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            script.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ROOT");
            script.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            script.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            script.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            script.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(HandleStdout);
            script.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(HandleStderr);
            script.Start();
```

I suspect it has something to do with the redirects: stdout hangs on the *[S,C]?* line because there's no newline after it. But I need these redirects...

There's of course a **3rd option** which is send an input of "continue" or empty line every second or so, so the script just has to look for "stop", but it's kind of ugly in my opinion so I'm trying to avoid it at all costs, especially if I get option 1 or 2 to work or get a better suggestion.

Comment: another possible option: look for a "flag" file: `if exist flag.txt exit`

Comment: But is there really no "normal" solution?

Comment: define "normal". Batchfiles run line by line. There is no "event handling" at all. So your only options are a "hard kill" or check something inside a loop without stopping the script.